# How to decompile .Net events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, xamarin, disassembly

Xamarin Assebly Browser produces the following code for an event

```
public event BooleanPreference.ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged {
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add {
        this.ValueChanged = (BooleanPreference.ValueChangedHandler)Delegate.Combine (this.ValueChanged, value);
    }
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove {
        this.ValueChanged = (BooleanPreference.ValueChangedHandler)Delegate.Remove (this.ValueChanged, value);
    }
}
```

Compiling it produces errors e.g.

```
Error CS0079: The event `EdB.Interface.BooleanPreference.ValueChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of `+=' or `-=' operator (CS0079) (EdB.Interface)
```

How do I convert the code to make it work?

Later in the code the event is referenced in

```
if ((!flag.HasValue || flag.Value != this.boolValue) && this.ValueChanged != null) {
    this.ValueChanged (value);
}
```

causing same error

```
Error CS0079: The event `EdB.Interface.BooleanPreference.ValueChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of `+=' or `-=' operator (CS0079) (EdB.Interface)
```

#### Edit:

The following code

```
public delegate void ValueChangedHandler (bool value);

public event BooleanPreference.ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged;

protected void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e) {
    var evt = ValueChanged;
    if (evt != null) {
        evt(this, e);
    }
}
```

produces

```
Error CS1593: Delegate `EdB.Interface.BooleanPreference.ValueChangedHandler' does not take `2' arguments (CS1593) (EdB.Interface)
```

Comment: That's because Xamarin decompiler doesn't handle the duality of an event. The event identifier can be used as a field internally but as an event externally. The decompiler should've decompiled it as a field, but it didn't, instead it decompiled it as an explicit event declaration with add/remove accessors. This makes all access to the event as the field illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic event declaration in C#, like this:

```
public event EventHandler EventName;
```

ends up giving you one identifier, `EventName`, that has two meanings, as that single declaration is used by the compiler to create two things:

1. A field, holding the delegate for the event
2. An event, declaring add and remove accessors to manipulate this field

However, you still only have one identifier, `EventName`, but its exact meaning depends on its context:

1. A reference to the field, whenever you're inside the class that declared the event
2. A reference to the event, whenever you're outside the class that declared the event

In reality, this kind of code is created:

```
private EventHandler _EventName;

public event EventHandler EventName
{
    add
    {
        _EventName = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_EventName, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        _EventName = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_EventName, value);
    }
}
```

However, since you used the basic syntax to declare the event the compiler will silently fix all references to either refer to the field (inside the class) or the event (outside the class).

Here's an example of an OnEventName method that you would write:

```
protected void OnEventName(...)
{
    var evt = EventName;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(this, ...);
}
```

The compiler will silently rewrite it to this:

```
protected void OnEventName(...)
{
    var evt = _EventName; // reference to the field
    if (evt != null)
        evt(this, ...);
}
```

Apparently the Xamarin decompiler doesn't understand this dual meaning. Basically you will have to rewrite the code according to the example above.

Comment: How do I initialize `evt` if the handler is `public delegate void ValueChangedHandler (bool value);`

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You call it with one, but please don't make this question a moving target. If you got a new question, ask a new question, don't keep adding to this one.

Comment: Call the event handler with just one bool parameter.

Comment: I posted code that would work how an event is typically defined, taking a `object sender, SomethingSomethingEventArgs e` parameter list, you didn't declare your event like that so no, you should not pass `this`, only your boolean parameter value.

Comment: I see, so `OnValueChanged(bool value)` has only `value` argument. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So you would call it with something like `evt(true);`

Comment: But what about `this.ValueChanged != null` etc should I keep them or replace with other code?

Comment: You should use the field in that expression, to check if the field has been assigned.

Comment: Just to make sure I get it -- I don't need to change it, right?

Comment: Do you think I can skip declaring `OnValueChanged(bool value)` and just keep using the decompiled code as shown in the original question, e.g. `if (this.ValueChanged != null) {this.ValueChanged (value);}`?